# Как написать сообщение, от имени бота, что сообщение удалено?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать код, чтобы бот написал, что сообщение удалено, чтобы, было адресовано пользователю, что администратор, удалил сообщение(публикацию), в группе телеграм.

Есть такой код, но не знаю, как через `for` или `if` прописать, чтобы писал текст, только, если администратор, удалил сообщение.

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_handler(message: types.Message):
    if message.text:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="\nПубликация удалена, администратором группы.".format(message.text, message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, message.message_id), parse_mode='html', disable_web_page_preview=True)
            return
```

Нашел, вот такой код, немножко переделал, работает, как надо, но только, по команде, в ответ, на сообщение, прописываю команду del и сообщение удаляется, как его изменить?, чтобы не по команде del

```html
@dp.message_handler(commands=['del'], commands_prefix="!/")
async def cmd_ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply('эта команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!')
        return

    await message.bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,message_id=message.reply_to_message.message_id)
    await message.reply("\nПубликация удалена.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну написано же там `commands` в хендлере, там пишите команды

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['удалить', 'del'], commands_prefix="!/")
```

очень советую посмотреть хотя бы пару видео по python и aiogram

Comment: Благодарю, подскажите пожалуйста, есть один минус, если отравляю галерею фото и в ответ, пишу команду, удаляется, только одно фото, как это исправить? чтобы всю галерею удаляло.

Comment: @Miki пожалуй для этой проблемы надо задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: Благодарю, уже создан, такой вопрос.